# Copy Files Over SSH to all servers in deployment group

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to setup CI pipeline for .net core app with VSTS.

I am confused with Copy Files Over SSH step. Server is defined not by deployment group but by endpoint host.

How should I copy my deployment artifacts to ALL servers in deployment group with this tool?

Actually, same applies to "SSH" - it also get executed only on host from Endpoint definition.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using deployment groups, you don't need to SSH anything to them. The build artifacts will be automatically downloaded to them, since the build/release agent is already running on them and talking directly to VSTS.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/debug-deployment-issues 
There is explicit step like "Deploy website to Azure" or "AzureBlob file copy". what can be used for linux?

Comment: @st78 I'd suggest asking separate questions in new forum threads. Thus, forum readers may recognize questions and answers easily. Is the original issue solved?

Comment: which task would I use to copy files with a deployment group?